# Math functions on number broken into Linked Lists in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have two large numbers, say 123,456,789 and 987,654,321 that are each broken up into segments of three into Linked List nodes (as ints), ][123] [456] [789]] and [[987] [654] [321]] and I need to perform math functions on them (add, subtract, multiply, divide).

I am at a complete loss as to how I can do them while the numbers are still separate. I also am not sure how to properly manage carry overs (ex. 999 + 11 = 1010, a number divided into two nodes)
The numbers need to stay in sets of three for the purposes of the problem as it should be able to handle numbers outside the scope of int, or other number classifications.

Comment: Why not just convert them to strings, concatenate the strings into one string, and then cast them back to integers (or doubles) for addition, subtraction, etc?

Comment: By the way, why to use linked list? Could we use standard list or an arraylist?

Comment: @David The program is supposed to be able to handle numbers larger than the max values for int, double, etc. so by breaking it up into smaller numbers, it becomes possible.
deporter the question said it has to be a linked list unfortunately.

Comment: @user1247751 Lets say an entry is linked list, i.e. [123],[456],[789] are nodes. what about the list of big numbers? Does [[123] [456] [789]] have to be a node of an another linked list?

Comment: @deporter I do not believe so.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the algorithms that you learned in elementary school (before you knew what an "algorithm" was) for performing arithmetic operations on multi-digit numbers?

That's basically what you need to implement here. Except that you're effectively working in base 1000 instead of base 10.

For instance, to implement addition, start by adding the first node (digit) of each number. The answer won't necessarily fit in a single node, but it will be smaller than twice that capacity, so it's not going to cause an overflow. Divide that number by the base (1000) and hold onto the remainder (using the `%` operator). Put the remainder in the first node of the sum.

Then, move on to the next node. When adding that node of each number, also add in the result of the division from the previous step. (This is the carrying part.) Repeat this process for all the nodes.

You can similarly translate all the operations from the elementary-school arithmetic algorithms. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Use java.math.BigInteger instead of linked list.
http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-biginteger/java-biginteger.shtml

Comment: For production code, this is the way to go, but the question is tagged as homework.